# How can I tell when a line in a textarea is made / deleted?

Tags: javascript, html, text, textarea

I have a textarea that is hooked up to line numbers that are made with an ordered list, but I want to be able to tell when a new line is created and when a line is deleted such as to add or delete ordered list elements such that the amount of ordered list elements
corresponds with the number of lines in the textarea.

I have figured that whenever a new line is created, the enter key is being used to do so, and that when a line is deleted, that sometimes happens when backspace is used.

I have event listeners for the textarea, with the id of "objtext", as so:

```js
//get the objtext element
var objtext=document.getElementById("objtext");

//detect keypress
objtext.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
  //detect new line
  if(e.key="Enter"){
    //add an ordered list element
  }
  if(e.key="Backspace"){
    //check what key was deleted
    //how can this be done?    
    if("\n" was removed){
      //remove an ordered list element
    }
    //and what about when a new line was removed?
    if(some text was removed such that it removes a line){
      //remove an ordered list element
    }
  }else if(some text was added such that it adds a line){
    //add an ordered list element
  }
});
```

But even if I could figure that out, the using enter to get a new line only works for new paragraphs, as in what about the times the text overflows the textarea onto a new line? And what about when backspace is used to delete some words such that it goes back up a line?

How could this be done?

Comment: Maybe the `textarea` was not good think for what your are trying to do. Could you send some text example for the input `textarea`?

Comment: Why not count line breaks (`\n`) of the content of the textarea on each change rather than keeping track of what button someone pushes?

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in the comments perhaps counting line breaks on each key stroke is easiest.

Note that when a line wraps due to insufficient space inside the `textarea`, we won't count the wrap as line break.

```js
const objtext = document.getElementById("objtext");

objtext.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  const output = document.getElementById("output");
  const lines = event.target.value.split('\n').length;

  // now do with lines what you like
  output.textContent = `The textarea has ${lines} line breaks`;
});
```

```css
#output {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="objtext"></textarea>

<span id="output">The textarea has 0 line breaks</span>
```

Comment: but could there be an answer that detects line breaks?

Comment: It does detect line breaks. What do you mean?

Comment: I meant line breaks as in when text overflows to a new line. Is there a way to detect that?

Comment: That should be a separate question as it's a very different field. Not sure how accurate you could do it with JS but you can certainly do things in CSS